# which framework is good for building barcode scanner mobile app?

Tags: ionic-framework, barcode, barcode-scanner, mobile-development

I'm planning to make an application that uses barcode scanning to scan UPC barcodes and maybe other barcode standards, I will be using firebase for database, I would like to have suggestions on which framework/tool for Mobile Development that I should use?

What I need in the framework is :

1. JS Libraries and packages support(NPM support would be Nice)
2. Community and tutorial Support(StackOverflow,github..etc)
3. CSS Libraries and icons support
4. Access to native features
5. I'll be developing for android but maybe I'll try to make it cross-platform later

I know about a  few frameworks/tools Like ionic3, React Native, Android studio but I'm not sure which I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently developing an app in Ionic and I used the native barcode-scanner plugin. For me it was easy to implement and works great. Ionic makes use of Cordova.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner

This plugin supports UPC_A and UPC_E barcodes.

2. Ionic has enough documentation and a start guide.
3. Ionic icons: [ionicons](https://ionicons.com/)
4. Access to native features: yes
5. Ionic can build to Android, IOS and windows.